# How to disable non-secure warning in IE6 with a non-secure external link?

Tags: ssl

I have a website with about 10 external links to other websites. Some of them have SSL, but some of them don't.

Everything works fine in all the browsers, except for the IE6. Users get "**This page contains both secure and nonsecure items**" message.

Is there a solution to get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure, that nothing is downloaded from unsecure sites, then there seems to be a bug in ie6. You can verify using http://www.whynopadlock.com/. Tested several times and can recommend.